# facebook android sdk 4.5 how to upload image with custom story from device

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i am having an app using FB android SDK v 4.5 where i want to upload image to facebook custom story directly from device or camera. i have created custom story even enabled user generated photo option in story setting(in object or action) in. 
below is code snippet i am try to use for custom story post.
How to attach image to directly to this code from device

```
    String shareTitle = bundle.getString("shareTitle");
    String shareUrl = bundle.getString("shareUrl");

    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    JSONObject myObject = new JSONObject();
    try {
        myObject.put("og:type", "in_myappnamespace:check_in");
        myObject.put("og:title", "Check out what i found on #myapptag "
                + shareTitle);
        if (shareUrl != null && !shareUrl.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
            myObject.put("og:url", shareUrl);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
    }
    params.putString("check_in", myObject.toString());
    params.putString("fb:explicitly_shared", "true");
    fbGraphRequest = new GraphRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
            "me/in_myappnamespace:share", params, HttpMethod.POST);
    new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            final GraphResponse response = fbGraphRequest.executeAndWait();
```

}}.start();

please help me, how to attach image with this request from android device.

thanks,